# Run Processing standalone on Linux

Tags: ubuntu, processing, executable, windows-7-x64

I created a standalone processing application on `Window7 64-bit` for `Linux 32-bit` and trying to run on Linux.

Before that, on windows it open by just double click on Application but on linux it's not.

Can anyone guide me on how do I run standalone on Linux(Ubuntu).

Comment: Have you flagged the file as executable? Does it run if started from a terminal window?

Comment: What version of Processing are you using? Are you running the Linux executable on Linux? Do you get any errors? Are you using the simplest possible sketch for testing purposes?

Comment: Processing version which Installd is `3.0a5`, I didn't run any processing program on Linux before, I just copy the whole standalone folder from my `Windows7 desktop` and paste into `Linux desktop`.

Comment: it is not simple, but now even it is not starting

Comment: @GoBusto I made it executable, but from which program should I associate it, in `open with`

Comment: Sorry, ignore my previous comment - I thought that you meant a "**p**rocessing application" not a [**P**rocessing](http://www.openprocessing.org/) application.

Comment: what 's the diff b/w "processing application" & Processing application

Comment: @IrfanGhaffar7 I think he just meant he didn't realize it was Processing, just a "general processing" question. But which executable are you running on Linux? Try to make it as simple as possible just for testing purposes.

Comment: it start working on Linux now ! thank you